# Resolving a vim plugin mapping conflict - mapping already exists for \t

Tags: python, vim, plugins, conflict

I followed http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide#intro to install a bunch of plugins for Python programming in gvim (installed on a Windows 8 machine).  It appears that there is a mapping conflict between the 'command-t' and 'tasklist' plugins, as I get the following error message:

```
>Error detected while processing C:\Users\Willem\vimfiles\bundle\tasklist\pl
>ugin\tasklist.vim:
>
>line  369:
>
>E227: mapping already exists for \t
```

Then I type :map in vim and see that one mapping is:

```
>n   \t             * :CommandT<CR>
```

Is there a good way to resolve this?

Answer (score 9):

tasklist will not map to `<leader>t` if a mapping to `<Plug>TaskList` is found.

So you just need to create a mapping to `<Plug>TaskList` in your vimrc. The example I found in the source code was

```
nnoremap <leader>v <Plug>TaskList
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more general explanation:

From the vim Help:

> Both `<SID>` and `<Plug>` are used to avoid that mappings of typed keys
>   interfere with mappings that are only to be used from other mappings. 
>   Note the difference between using `<SID>` and `<Plug>`:
>
> `<Plug>`  is visible outside of the script.  It is used for mappings
>   which the     user might want to map a key sequence to.  `<Plug>` is a
>   special code  that a typed key will never produce.    To make it very
>   unlikely that other plugins use the same sequence of  characters, use
>   this structure:  scriptname mapname     In our example the
>   scriptname is "Typecorr" and the mapname is "Add".    This results in
>   "TypecorrAdd".  Only the first character of     scriptname and
>   mapname is uppercase, so that we can see where mapname    starts.

So If you want that the error doesn't appear, you need to map something to `<Plug>Tasklist` in your sample.

Like this:

```
nnoremap <leader>v <Plug>TaskList
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, maybe imperfect, solution would be to directly edit `tasklist.vim`around line 369 and manually change the mapping that is done there.